# Reporting Services incorrect icon on show/hide group

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have created a parameter on a report that allows the user to open all the group details or hide group details when the report is run.

This works, but when you run the report and select to expand the groups, the little icon use use to show/hide on the report is a + symbol instead of a - one.

While the actual report is right, i can see it confusing the users somewhat as it looks like there is something hidden, when in fact its all there -

[alt text http://www.beakersoft.co.uk/img/report_icons.gif](http://www.beakersoft.co.uk/img/report_icons.gif)

Any one seen this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the initial appearance of the toggle icon for the  textbox properties (The textbox that controls the visibility of a row/group). You can find this setting under the Visibility tab of the textbox properties dialog box. Use an expression to determine the initial appearance of the icon for different toggle items.

See [this short article](http://www.lukehayler.com/2009/07/custom-visibility-toggling-in-ssrs/) for more info:

Answer (score 11):

This problem (wrong display of plus-minus tiny toggle icon) occurs when you want to initially set the Visibility as Show, in the Group Properties (bottom left pane, Row Groups, right click). The solution is to:

1. Click the text box where the toggle icon should appear
2. At the property pane, near the bottom, under the Visibility, set InitialToggleState to True

Comment: Is there a way to set that in Report Builder instead of using BIDS to get at the properties?  Using Report Builder, I have the groups initially expanded that I want, but they show the incorrect sign.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. 
To resolve this issue Make InitialToggleState property of text box on which display is toggled conditional.

Like this

```
=iif(Parameters!DrillDown.Value,true,false)
```

And my show or hide is based on expression

```
=iif(Parameters!DrillDown.Value,false,true)
```